# I can't change jekyll syntax highlighter at my github blog

Tags: ruby, jekyll, syntax-highlighting, github-pages, rouge

I made my github blog.
I want to change my syntax highlighter to rouge.
I do this.

```sh
gem install rouge
rougify style monokai.sublime > assets/css/syntax.css
```

```
//default.html
link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/syntax.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```
// _config.yml
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    default_lang: html
    css_class   : 'syntax'
```

But my blog's syntax highlighter stay none.

How can I change this?

https://github.com/azzyjk/azzyjk.github.io.
https://azzyjk.github.io/GithubBlog_2/

[Chrome DevTools Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxycM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the command line instructions with the jekyll instructions. Also it seems that your command `rougify style monokai.sublime` does not work properly as if I look at the CSS file in your blog it says `unknown theme: monokaisubline` (https://azzyjk.github.io//assets/css/syntax.css).

So easiest solution just c&p one of these CSS stylesheets into your `style.css` files https://github.com/jwarby/jekyll-pygments-themes.

Here are the Jekyll docs https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#code-snippet-highlighting

### Edit:

As CSS is now correct but the correct CSS classes are not applied to your code snippets, can you try to set your syntax highlighter in your jekyll config.

```yaml
kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  input: GFM
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I want to apply 'monokai.sublime' but I apply "monokai.subline'. So I change my syntax.css to 'monokai.sublime'. But it doesn't work too. Refresh this page it apply syntax highlighter a little minute.

Comment: See my edit, can you try to set the `syntax_highlighter` option in the `kramdown` block to `rouge`.

Comment: I fix my _config.yml file but it looks same.
I think 'memoir' theme is too kind.
So, it have default syntax-highlighter.
And I think, it hinder rouge syntax-highlighter...

Comment: Look my chrome devtools picture.
'prism.css' & 'theme.css' affect '.highlight'