# Jekyll Rouge washed out Monokai color

Tags: css, jekyll, syntax-highlighting, redcarpet, rouge

I'm using Github Pages Jekyll static website generator with Cayman theme on Rouge Monokai syntax highlighting on [my website](https://pippim.github.io).

I used the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62663202/6929343).

I copied the scss from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwarby/pygments-css/master/monokai.css

And posted it into `assets/css/style.scss` on the website.

Non-language markdown color formatting has faint text:

[image: jekyll rouge default.png]

This isn't the question but it is easier to read like `pycharm` doc string good ole monochrome monitor green:

[image]

## The BIG problem

When it comes to Github's default markdown (for Python) it looks OK when previewed:

[image: jekyll rouge markdown github style.png]

However when you save the page, Krampdown or RedCarpet or whomever generates the HTML incorrectly using the **``` python** code block:

[image: jekyll rouge markdown python error.png]

If it helps here is the content of my `_config.yml`:

```yaml
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
title: pippim - Open-source
description: Free open-source software for the World. Free of Ads too!

kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  input: GFM
```

How can I get **Rouge** formatting to work properly using the Monokai theme?